# Can't create a Kubernetes Service on Azure

Tags: kubernetes, azure-container-service, azureportal

I am unable to create a Kubernetes Service on Azure through the portal.

The steps I am taking are

> MyResourceGroup -> Add+ -> Select 'Kubernetes Service' from the store.

I have filled in the form completely and all boxes are complete. All the fields that have the 'tick' icon have 'green ticks'. I am double checking every panel.

However when I click create I get an error at the bottom of the page with a red exclamation mark saying...

> 'Please fix the errors on this page before continuing.'

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See comments in Karishma's post

> Problem was the region. I was selecting 'UK South' once I selected
>   'West Europe' it went through

Answer (score 0):

@Lenny There are multiple tabs in the process, for example Basics, authentication etc. 
Which tab are you getting the error on?
Make sure you have the right service principal added under the Authentication tab.

I reproduced the scenario and was able to create Kubernetes Service without any errors. 
I would recommend retrying it by following the step by step guide for creating a AKS service [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough-portal#create-an-aks-cluster).

Please make sure you see the **Validation passed** at the top, while on the **Review + create** tab as below:

[image]

Let me know if you still see errors.

Comment: I have it set to create a new service principal and has a green tick. I have checked all the tabs. I don't get the validation passed at the top

Comment: Happy to share my desktop on skype if you like? I have created a one time ticket on Azure just email me on the 'ian' email linked to the ticket

Comment: Thanks for sharing. What Kubernetes version are you selecting under the Basics tab? Can you try changing that and see if that works?
I cannot connect to you via skype, but since you have opened a support ticket, you will be contacted by the support team shortly and you can have skype conversation with them.

Comment: Was selecting the latest 1.11.1. Tried other versions but still not working.

Comment: Ok finally worked this out! Problem was the region. I was selecting 'UK South' once I selected 'West Europe' it went through, No error messages though so this is definitely a bug or some issue with the region on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use "[Azure Cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest)"

```
az login    
az group create --name {nameofthegroup} --location southeastasia
```

Currently, aks is only available in this regions

Available location: eastus,westeurope,centralus,canadacentral,canadaeast,uksouth,westus,westus2,australiaeast,northeurope